# Javascript change multiple elements border style one at a time onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As a JavaScript rookie I'm still learning as my site grows, and have been battling for the past 12 hours with this.

**What my site does**

- Player select team who they think will win match.
- Matches/Fixtures are pulled from database
- Player makes pick for the round, a round can have 1 to countless matches
- nr of elements(images and radio btns) created in php loop will depend on nr of matches for given round

**What I am trying to do**

- When user selects a team/clicks on it, make selected teams image-border:red

**What I've got**

*HTML*

```
echo'<div class="teams">';
        echo'<img src="images/teams/'.$src1.'.png" class="t1"  />'; 
        echo'<img src="images/teams/'.$src2.'.png" class="t2" />';  
    echo'</div>';

 <!--Radio Buttons below comment-->
 <label class="blue"><input type="radio"  onclick="border()" name="picks['.$x.']" id="one" value="'.$row['team1'].'"><span>'.$team1.'</span></label><br />
    <label class="green"><input type="radio"  onclick="border()" name="picks['.$x.']" id="two" value="'.$row['team2'].'"><span>'.$team2.'</span></label><br />
    <label class="green"><input type="radio"  onclick="" name="picks['.$x.']" id="three" value="draw"><span>Draw</span></label><br />
```

*Jquery attempt one*

```
function border() {
    var oneChecked = $('#one').is(':checked');
    var twoChecked = $('#two').is(':checked');

    $('.t1').each(function(){
       if(oneChecked)
       {
         $(this).siblings('t2').css({'border':'none'});
         $(this).css({'border':'1px solid red'});
       }
       else if(twoChecked)
       {
         $(this).css({'border':'none'});
         $(this).siblings('t2').css({'border':'1px solid red'});
       }
    });   
}
```

**Problem**

All the team1 borders are selected with all the matches with a single click(see img below)

*Image*

[image]

*Javascript attempt 2*

```
function border() {
    var el = document.getElementsByClassName("t1")[0];
     var el2 = document.getElementsByClassName("t2")[0];
    if (document.getElementById("one").checked) { 

        el.style.borderColor = "red";
        el.style.borderStyle = "solid";
           el2.style.borderColor = "";
        el2.style.borderStyle = "none";
    }

      else if (document.getElementById("two").checked) { 
       el.style.borderColor = "";
        el.style.borderStyle = "none";
        el2.style.borderColor = "red";
        el2.style.borderStyle = "solid";
    }

}
```

**Problem**

Only 1st match team border gets selected, when I move to match 2 nothing happens(see img)

*Image*

[image]

Comment: Can you try to make a pen or fiddle of a simplified example?

Comment: ok will do give me a minute

Comment: @connexo https://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=DUcgKrLnOu

Comment: That link leads to a collaborative fiddle session with an empty fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides it not working, another issue with the original code is that the radio buttons do not have unique ids.

The solution is to associate each set of radio buttons with a set of images. This can be done by wrapping each group of elements with a container element.

```
<!-- This repeats for each group. -->
<div class="teamContainer">

<div class="teams">
    <span class="team team1">TEAM 1</span>
    <span class="team team2">TEAM 2</span>
</div>

<label><input type="radio" name="picks[0]" value=".team1"/>Team 1</label><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="picks[0]" value=".team2"/>Team 2</label><br />
<label><input type="radio" name="picks[0]" value=""/>Draw</label><br />

</div>
```

This way you can use `.closest()` to go from a radio button to the container element. Then you can use `.find()` to work with just the images in that group.

```
$(function() {
    $('.teamContainer').on('change', ':radio', function() {
        var $container = $(this).closest('.teamContainer'),
            $teams = $container.find('.teams'),
            value = $container.find(':radio:checked').val();
        $teams.find('.team').css({'border':'none'});
        $teams.find(value).css({'border':'1px solid red'});
    });
});
```

You should bind event handlers, rather then use `onclick` attributes. Also, I think it is better to use the "change" event, instead of the "click" event.

One more thing, notice that I set the value of the radio button to a selector. This way you can avoid the if-statements.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cjycaruc/)

Comment: ...I really want to say a big thank you not only for your working solutions but taking the time to point out the steps and explain it to me. Thanks mate

Comment: Im having trouble getting this to work inside my php code, please let me know if you are available and kind enough to help me out, many thanks

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee - Sorry, I'm shutting down for the night. It's 2 am here.

Comment: No worrys mate, hope to catch you later, ps do I need to call this function anywhere?

Comment: Like onclick on the radio button

Comment: @TimothyCoetzee - Just put the JavaScript in my answer in a `<script>` element. That code calls the `$` function, passing it an anonymous callback function. jQuery calls the callback function when the page loads, just after the DOM is ready. That is the common way to bind event handlers.

Answer (score 1):

Run this. This should do what you are looking for.

1st, the each selector was only selecting a single item: $('.t1').each

2nd, the $(this).siblings('t2') is missing a period in selector.

```js
function border() {
    var oneChecked = $('#one').is(':checked');
    var twoChecked = $('#two').is(':checked');

    $('img').each(function(){
       if(oneChecked)
       {
         $(this).siblings('.t2').css({'border':'none'});
         $(this).siblings('.t1').css({'border':'1px solid red'});
       }
       else if(twoChecked)
       {
         $(this).siblings('.t1').css({'border':'none'});
         $(this).siblings('.t2').css({'border':'1px solid red'});
       }
    });   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="teams">
<img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-nnu1pYWswh4/UP1qvA5yiRI/AAAAAAAAAw4/8Jj_vj_wwG8/s1600/superhero_cartoons_l943.jpg" class="t1" width="200px" height: 300px; />;
<img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-nnALU6o_LnM/UP1rBXHumcI/AAAAAAAAAxY/nc1RB0ZSUqU/s1600/superheroes_l623.jpg" class="t2" height="300px" width="200px "/>  
</div>

 <!--Radio Buttons below comment-->
 <label class="blue">
 <input type="radio"  onclick="border()" name="picks['.$x.']" id="one" value="'.$row['team1'].'"><span>'.$team1.'</span></label><br />

<label class="green">
<input type="radio"  onclick="border()" name="picks['.$x.']" id="two" value="'.$row['team2'].'"><span>'.$team2.'</span></label><br />
    <label class="green"><input type="radio"  onclick="" name="picks['.$x.']" id="three" value="draw"><span>Draw</span></label><br />
```

Comment: thanks but what if you have more images try adding another set in there with another set of radio buttons

Comment: you could give your images a class name then iterate .each over the class selector.

Comment: gonna give it a go tellez, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This can actually be solved with simple css! No need for that fancy jQuery! ;)

```css
input[type="radio"]{
    display:none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label
{
    background: #999;
    border: none;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label
{
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 0 0 0 0px;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="radio" id="1" name="1" checked></input>
  <label for="1"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="2" name="1" ></input>
  <label for="2"></label>
</form>
<br>
<form>
  <input type="radio" id="3" name="2" checked></input>
  <label for="3"></label>
  <input type="radio" id="4" name="2" ></input>
  <label for="4"></label>
</form>
```

From here you can simply change the width/height and add a `background-image:`, and voilà you have what you want! I should point out that it is very important that the `name` attribute in the `input` tags must be identical! :)

Comment: thanks but what if there is a next set of images with a next set of radio buttons

Comment: Okay, take a look at the edit!! :)

Comment: wow wow wow, that  is impressive css skills mate

Comment: I just lovee me some css! ;)

Comment: jaunt do you know php? What im going to do is but a variable $x as the div id and then increment him by 1 after every loop, not the best practice but it should work, what do you think

Comment: That should work! And then for the name, div x by 2 and floor it.

Comment: @JohnS Do you want to post that as an answer and I will accept it, thanks so much everyone